# How to close running instance of application on repair in installshield in Basic MSI Project?

Tags: installation, installshield, installation-package

I want to close running instance of my application on repair option of my setup....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done through a custom action. There is no predefined support for it, so you will need to write your own custom code. A good approach is sending WM_CLOSE to the main application window and let it close itself.

To run this custom action only during repair, you can try conditioning it with [REINSTALL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa371175%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) property.

If you want to avoid the Files In Use dialog, you will need to run this custom action before [InstallValidate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa369546%28VS.85%29.aspx) action. In this case you cannot use REINSTALL property, but you can use this condition:

```
Installed
```

It evaluates to true when your package is running in maintenance mode (modify, repair or remove).

Comment: Thanks Cosmin Pirvu,
I created custom action in VB Script, and it successfully worked...:)